# How can I get Html of a website as seen on browser?

Tags: python

A website loads a part of the site after the site is opened, when I use libraries such as request and urllib3, I cannot get the part that is loaded later, how can I get the html of this website as seen in the browser. I can't open a browser using Selenium and get html because this process should not slow down with the browser.

I tried htppx, httplib2, urllib, urllib3 but I couldn't get the later loaded section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) library or [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) to simulate a user-like page loading and waiting to load additional HTML elements.

I would suggest using [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) since it contains the [WebDriverWait](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) Class that can help you scrape the additional HTML elements.

This is my simple example:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Replace with the URL of the website you want
url = "https://www.example.com"

# Adding the option for headless browser
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

# Create a new instance of the Chrome webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

# Wait for the additional HTML elements to load
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[contains(@class, 'lazy-load')]")))

# Get  HTML 
html = driver.page_source

print(html)

driver.close()
```

In the example above you can see that I'm using an [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to wait (10secs) for a specific condition to occur. More specifically, I'm waiting until the element with the 'lazy-load' class is located [By.XPath](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html?highlight=by.xpath#locating-by-xpath) and then I retrieve the HTML elements.

Finally, I would recommend checking both [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) and [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev/) since both have tremendous capabilities for scrapping websites and automating web-based tasks.

Comment: The specs of the computer I will use this code on are pretty low. That's why I didn't want to use selenium because the computer has trouble even opening firefox. But in this situation I must do dynamic scraping so it means I must use Selenium. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Asidistaken You can use a headless browser that runs without rendering the graphics and doesn't consume resources from your computer.